# 'full screen' and 'close' buttons in FancyBox

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox-3

I'm using FancyBox v3.0.47 for Ajax (html files).  Our testers noticed that the Full Screen and Close buttons are obscured by the vertical scroll area of the modal screen.

Is there a way to adjust the right margin of the controls to move the controls to the left about 12px?  I tried setting the right margin in the following CSS, but that didn't work. Am I at the correct control, or should I be looking somewhere else?

```
.fancybox-controls {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 99994;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  direction: ltr; }
```

Comment: do you have a some code example?

Comment: Another simple solution would be to move buttons to the left side using CSS.

Comment: Or make your content scrollable instead of the whole slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:
right: 0;

to:
right:12px;

Comment: This worked!  For the record, 18px is perfect to move the control out of the way of the scroll bar.